# Mixed Date format in table column

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have noticed some dates in one table are stored like 21/08/2014 or 21/08/14 so when I run my parameter dates i dd/mm/yyyy it will miss some records out.  How best ca I format this table colum to ensure this doesnt happen?

Answer (score 1):

To correct erroneous data in that column you could do a find and replace on "/14" changing to "/2014".

To prevent future erroneous data entry you could go into the table's properties and use an input mask to only accept dd/mm/yyyy dates.